# undefined reference to `StitchedMap::get_stitch()'

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I am new to ROS.

I am trying to convert the Mapstitch package (https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch) from Rosbuild to Catkin. However, after I created a catkin package and modified the CMakeList, there are some errors when I compile the package. Could anyone tell what's the problem?

ROS: Indigo
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Errors

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/lok/ws/devel/lib/mapstitch/mapstitch] Error 1
make[1]: *** [mapstitch/CMakeFiles/mapstitch.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable /home/lok/ws/devel/lib/mapstitch/main
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x99f): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::StitchedMap(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, float)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9e0): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::get_stitch()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xbaa): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::get_stitch()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xc5b): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::get_stitch()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd6f): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::get_debug()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe20): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::get_debug()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xeeb): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::~StitchedMap()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x16fc): undefined reference to `StitchedMap::~StitchedMap()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/lok/ws/devel/lib/mapstitch/main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [mapstitch/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mapstitch)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
  cv_bridge
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES mapstitch
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp tf cv_bridge
  DEPENDS system_lib OpenCV
)


include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${mapstitch})
include_directories(include mapstitch)
include_directories(include tclap)

add_executable(rosmain src/rosmain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rosmain ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(rosmain ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(main ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(mapstitch src/mapstitch.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mapstitch ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(mapstitch ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287163/undefined-reference-to-%60stitchedmap::get_stitch()%27/) by [LokJai](https://answers.ros.org/users/34415/lokjai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [hector_mapstitch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch/tree/hector_mapstitch) branch seems to contain a version that is already migrated to Catkin.

As to your problem: not all those `.cpp` files are stand-alone programs. At least the `main` target seems to also require the `src/mapstitch.cpp` as part of its source list.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LokJai](https://answers.ros.org/users/34415/lokjai/) on 2018-04-01**:
Great, then I don't have to convert it by myself.
One more thing to ask, the package listens to three topics /map, /world, /align but how can I obtain the stitched map and share to two robots?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-01**:
It's considered 'bad form' to ask follow-up questions in comments under accepted answers on ROS Answers (any Q&A site really), unless they are conceptually close to the OP or ask for clarification of certain aspect of the answer. Seeing as neither is the case here, I suggest you post a new question.